# SQL for identifying and spreading overlapping points on map

Tags: leaflet, cartodb

I'm working on a map with the birth place of all nobel laureates. As I only have the birth place on city level, there are a lot of overlapping points that I'm trying to find a way to spread.

http://s3.mapfact.com/society/all-nobel-prize-laureates/nobel.html

My data is in Carto. I would like to do some SQL to:
1. Identify rows with the same lat/lng in the_geom column
2. On each match - add a few points to the values so the markers are not 100% overlapping.

I have found this and I like the outcome, but it's far too advanced for me http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/raw/8695515/#

Any ideas for a more simple way to do it? e.g. something that involves a couple of steps in the Carto db-interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the technique explained at [this blog post](https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack/). You'll see a working example here:

https://team.carto.com/u/jsanz/builder/4ddc4fd8-fcb5-11e5-914a-0ef7f98ade21/embed

[image]

And the SQL that defines the layer here:

https://gist.github.com/jsanz/13e635b55a0bbee5a4acb27b4a3e7c48

Don't be scared by the SQL you only need to put your field names at the end and of course the table name (`team` in my example) and you'll have it. Then you can add the category symbolization, infowindows or tooltips as you wish.

The only limitation is that this works well for only a few zooms but you can disable that on your map as normally these kind of maps only make sense at low zoom levels.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! For some reason it didn't work when I used the sql directly in the map source, but I ran the SQL in Carto's interface and created a new data set from the results. http://s3.mapfact.com/society/all-nobel-prize-laureates/

Comment: glad it worked! maybe you can mark now the answer as correct?
:-)

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not be a correct answer to your question, it might be a solution to your problem. For a similar situation I had, I used [leaflet markercluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). If you have more then one marker on a same [lat, lng] when you click on it it will move all of them around and you won't get an overlap. See the images bellow:

With the clustering:
[image]

After the user clicks on the cluster:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Marko, but I am actually already doing this. The problem with this is too things: 
1. You have to zoom in to the highest zoom level (yes, it's easy because it's just clicking on the marker cluster) - and then you have to click again to get them spiderfied. It's a little annoying.
2. I could be satisfied with the cluster solution, but I have a problem - if I change category (click on the l.control element) while markers are spiderfied I get a script error I have already spent days to try to fix.

Comment: @JesperSidorNielsen which version of Leaflet.markercluster do you use? Version 0.5.0 (for Leaflet 0.7) and 1.0.0 (for Leaflet 1.0) should have solved the issue of having to zoom to max before being able to spiderfy markers at the same lat-lng. As for categories, you might be interested in [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) plugin (I am the author of that plugin)

Comment: You can also try to use to use [OverlappingMarker](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) plugin for Leaflet. Not sure about your problems with L.control element, I would need to see the code for this.

Comment: @ghybs. You were right. I changed to newer version, it works now. Thanks.